# Best way to get most precise location on mobile with js only

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a webapp/pwa where I need a precise user location, say under 30-40 meters, I have tried using Radar.io, as well as the geolocation api but still have not been able to get a precise enough location on my iphone on safari. I usually get 60-70 meter accuracy, how would I get more accurate than this? I want the accuracy to be that of the Nike Run Club app for reference.

Comment: I also have precise location tracking enabled on my ios device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the Geolocation API many times and it's very precise if you configure it properly.

Here's a snippet I've used in a similar project:

```js
// check if geolocation is supported on this browser
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  const timeoutVal = 10 * 1000 * 1000; // set a timeout value for the query
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    // what to do if query succeeds
    ((position) => alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude)),
    ((error) => {
      // what to do if query fails:
       const errors = {
         1: 'Permission denied',
         2: 'Position unavailable',
         3: 'Request timeout'
       };

       alert("Error: " + errors[error.code]); // print the error
    }),
    // these 3 parameters are very important, especially the first one
    { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 }
  );
}
else {
  alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the `maximumAge` and `timeout` paramters?

Comment: Also do you happen to have a rough estimate of the accuracy in meters with this approach?

Comment: @svoruganti hey, I tried that on my phone and it pointed right to my home address. The point of `maximumAge` is to tell the browser that it can't use a cached geolocation.

Comment: what about the `timeout` paramater? And does this continuously get the current position? If so what's the difference between this and `watchPosition()`?

Comment: @svoruganti timeout just tells how much time to wait before telling the browser to stop searching geoposition. I don't know what you mean by continuously, could you please elaborate?

Comment: as in continuously I mean run every x ms perhaps using `setInterval()`?

Comment: @svoruganti No. You run it whenever you want - it doesn't spawn any timers / event listeners.